# function template with stl container as an input

Tags: c++, stl

I am getting compilation error is following code. I thought this should have worked in c++
Can anybody help me to understand what is wrong here.

```
template < typename elem_type>
elem_type *find2( std::vector<elem_type>& vec, elem_type value) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        if ( vec[i] == value ) {
            return &vec[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int main( int argc, char **argv) {
    int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    std::vector<int> vec( arr, arr+10);     
    int value = 9;
    int *ptr1 = find2(vec,value);
}
```

following is the compilation error

```
1>          d:\personal\work\find\find\find.cpp(25) : see reference to function template instantiation 'elem_type *find2<int>(std::vector<_Ty> &,elem_type &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              elem_type=int,
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
```

compiler is `Visual Studio 11`

Comment: Why not post the complete error message?

Comment: You know that you could use `std::find(arr, arr + 10, 9)`...?

Comment: I just compiled the code with g++ and it compiled without an error. I did add "#include <vector>". When I add "std::cout << *ptr1 << std::endl;" it outputs the correct answer. So... your compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line,

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i ) {
```

you are comparing the signed `int` variable `i` to the unsigned `size_t` result of `vec.size()`.

The compiler warns because such a comparision is unsafe in the face of *implicit promotions* in C++. `i` is promoted to `size_t`. If `i` were (hypothetically) negative, that would produce a really huge value, and would thus produce an unexpected comparision result.

A simple cure is to

```
    #include <stddef.h>
    typedef ptrdiff_t Size;
    typedef Size Index;
```

and then do e.g.

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < Size( vec.size() ); ++i ) {
```

You will probably get at least one answer recommending the apparently simpler

```
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i ) {
```

but this is problematic for the same reason that the compiler warned: using unsigned integers *as numbers* risks getting very weird and unexpected results, buggy results, due to implicit promotions and in general conversion from negative number to unsigned, or vice versa.

Even better than the casting above, define a `countOf` function like

```
    template< class Container >
    Size countOf( Container const& c ) { return v.size(); }

    template< class Elem, Size n >
    Size countOf( Elem (&)[n] ) { return n; }
```

and then write just

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < countOf( vec ); ++i ) {
```

And best, forget about that indexing and use iterators:

```
    for ( auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it ) {
```

Answer (score 4):

It is best to use a variable of the same type as the index used in the container. In this case, you want a `size_t` or a `size_type`. They correspond with the types used in the vector's [size](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/size/) and [operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/operator%5B%5D/) functions.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i)
{
    myVector[i]++;
}
```

If you need to iterate in reverse, simply maintain an internal index.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i)
{
    size_t j = myVector.size() - i - 1;
    myVector[j]++;
}
```

If you need to perform signed math, again, maintain an internal casting.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i)
{
    int j = (int)i;
    myVector[i] += j;
}
```

Comment: -1 This adds complexity and bug-attractors (mostly via implicit conversions) for no good reason.

Comment: Using [size_t](http://critical.eschertech.com/2010/04/07/danger-unsigned-types-used-here/) seems to be a controversial subject, interesting to say the least.

Comment: This is where discipline comes in. The `i` variable is here to iterate over a collection. If you need to do complex math with it, make a local variable cast to correct type.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental problem you have is that you are mixing signed and unsigned integers. Your index variable is a signed type, but the vector's size() member function returns an unsigned type. Mixing types like this can cause errors. If a signed value like -1 gets assigned to an unsigned variable, a very large value is usually the result.

The idiomatic way to iterate over a standard library container is to use standard library iterators.

```
for (std::vector<elem_type>::iterator it=vec.begin(); it<vec.end(); ++it)
{
    if ( *it == value ) {
        return &(*it);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works too. Ultimately, math performed on the for-loop's iterator should always be separated anyway. It pains me to see people QQ'ing over how scary unsigned values are.